# ArgumentException While connecting win phone 8.1 to wcf

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8.1, argumentexception

While building win phone 8.1 Silverlight, 
Added service reference to WCF, some method for reference:

```
    [OperationContract]
    Task<GetPlayListResponse> GetPlayList(GetPlayListRequest request);
```

And using it like this:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var service = new MediaServiceClient();
        service.GetPlayListCompleted += service_GetPlayListCompleted;
        GetPlayListRequest request = new GetPlayListRequest { BusinessId = 41 };
        service.GetPlayListAsync(request);

    }

    void service_GetPlayListCompleted(object sender, MediaService.GetPlayListCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var response =  e.Result;
        if (response.Result.ResultCode == eRequestResultCode.Success)
        {
            lb_RequestList.ItemsSource = response.Songs;
        }

    }
```

Getting the following error message:

```
[System.ArgumentException]  {System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)}    System.ArgumentException
```

The exception is accruing here :

```
        public WinPhone.Silverlight_Client.MediaService.GetPlayListResponse EndGetPlayList(System.IAsyncResult result) {
            object[] _args = new object[0];
            WinPhone.Silverlight_Client.MediaService.GetPlayListResponse _result = ((WinPhone.Silverlight_Client.MediaService.GetPlayListResponse)(base.EndInvoke("GetPlayList", _args, result)));
            return _result;
        }
```

Comment: You pass '_args' to base.EndInvoke, but it looks as if it has not been set to anything. Could this be your problem?

Comment: No.. tried it already. 
This code is generated by the add service reference wizard